# Selenium and capture object

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using firefox and marking a link in my web-app I get among other things, this code which I think I can use to caprture an object:

```
cb_or_somename_someothername cb_area_0219
```

This string is "classname" in Firebug.
Going to the script I type in:

```
WebElement rolle = driver.findElement(By.className("cb_or_somename_someothername cb_area_0219"));
```

But the script does not find the element when executing.

Other onfo in the Firebug panel is:

```
class="cb_or_somename_someothername cb_area_0219"


onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'$(this).attr(\'disabled\',   \'disabled\');return true;','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'fwMainContentForm\'),{\'fwMainContentForm:j_idt156:2:selectRole \':\'fwMainContentForm:j_idt156:2:selectRole\'},\'\')');return false"


href="#"


id="fwMainContentForm:j_idt156:2:selectRole"
```

Is my script referring the element in a wrong way?

Comment: Did you get `ElementNotFoundException` or exception about compound class name?

Comment: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector cb_or_somename_someothername cb_area_0219 is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use search by compound class name (name with spaces). Try to use search by `CSS` selector instead:

```
WebElement rolle = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".cb_or_somename_someothername.cb_area_0219"));
```

or by `XPath`:

```
WebElement rolle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='cb_or_somename_someothername cb_area_0219']"));
```

Also you still can use search by one of two class names:

```
WebElement rolle = driver.findElement(By.className("cb_or_somename_someothername"));
```

or

```
WebElement rolle = driver.findElement(By.className("cb_area_0219")); // Note that this class name could be generated dynamically, so each time it could has different decimal part
```

**Update**

If you get `Element is not clickable...` exception it seem that your element is covered by another element at the moment you try to click on it. So try to wait until this "cover" is no more visible:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//p[@class='environtment-banner']"));
WebElement rolle = driver.findElement(By.className("cb_area_0219")); 
rolle.click();
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131898/discussion-on-answer-by-andersson-selenium-and-capture-object).